# Using k3s Traefik Installation to Reverse Proxy External Apps/Webpages

Tags: kubernetes, reverse-proxy, traefik, k3s

TLDR: I cant use Traefik running in k3s to reverse proxy application not in k3s, i.e. Portainer running on Synology

I'm currently in the process of migrating away from UNRAID and have built out a 6 node cluster with 3 Proxmox vms, and 3 Raspberry Pi 4s. Everything is working pretty well inside the cluster. On UNRAID I have a docker container for Traefik that acts as my reverse proxy to all my hosted services. Most of which have/will be moved to the k3s cluster and said clusters Traefik installation can proxy those just fine. The issue I'm running into is I cant seem to get Traefik to proxy to external apps/webpages that are not in the cluster. For instance my Portainer installation on my Synology.

Things I have set.

Made endpoint

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: portainer-service
  namespace: utilities
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: {SYNOLOGYIP}
    ports:
      - port: 9000 #portainer port running on Synology, its accessible
        protocol: TCP
```

Made service using the same name as the endpoint. Tried as headless, ClusterIP, and ExternalName

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: portainer-service
  namespace: utilities
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.43.213.93
  clusterIPs:
    - 10.43.213.93
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
    - name: portainer-service
      port: 9000 #Tried this on just port 80/443 as well
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9000 #Tried this on just port 80/443 as well
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Created the ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: portainer-ingress
  namespace: utilities
spec:
  ingressClassName: traefik
  rules:
    - host: portainer.k3s.lab.DOMAIN.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: portainer-service
                port:
                  number: 9000
            path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - kube-wildcard-tls
```

I have also tried it as an IngressRoute

```
---
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: portainer.route
  namespace: utilities

spec:
  entryPoints:
    - portainer-service

  routes:
  - match: Host(`portainer.k3s.lab.DOMAIN.com`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: portainer-service
      port: 80 #Port 9000 tried here as well
```

DNS is working for *.k3s.lab.DOMAIN.com internally, with round robin A records pointing to all 6 nodes.

In the Helm install values I also set `allowExternalNameServices: true` Not sure if this is important...

```
providers:
  kubernetesCRD:
...
    allowExternalNameServices: true
...
  kubernetesIngress:
...
    allowExternalNameServices: true
...
    ingressEndpoint:
      publishedService: default/traefik
```

Am I just trying something here that isn't possible? I don't love the idea of maintaining two reverse proxies, although it wouldn't be the end of the world as I don't have anything exposed externally so I won't have to worry about port forward conflicts. I would just like to keep it all in one place.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.